# toMap on List of List generates error

Tags: scala

Given that this example:

```
val myList = List("age=21", "name=xyz", "profession=Tester", "city=cuba", "age=43", "name=abc", "profession=Programmer", "city=wellington")
val myMap = myList.map(text => text.split("=")).map(a => (a(0) -> a(1))).toMap
```

works fine, returning:

```
myList: List[String] = List(age=21, name=xyz, profession=Tester, city=cuba, age=43, name=abc, profession=Programmer, city=wellington)
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(age -> 43, name -> abc, profession -> Programmer, city -> wellington)
```

I am wondering why the following which is just N sets of values:

```
val myList = List("age=21", "name=xyz", "profession=Tester", "city=cuba", "age=43", "name=abc", "profession=Programmer", "city=Sydney")
val myMap = myList.grouped(4).toList.map(text => text.split("=")).map(a => (a(0) -> a(1))).toMap
```

generates the error, and how to solve:

```
notebook:9: error: value split is not a member of List[String]
val myMap = myList.grouped(4).toList.map(text => text.split("=")).map(a => (a(0) -> a(1))).toMap
```

I must be missing something elementary here.

Comment: What are you expecting the type of myMap to be, exactly? Your problem is that `myList.grouped(4).toList` is a `List[List[String]]` (not a `List[String]`), as such the map function needs to take `List[String]` (or super-type) as its input.

Comment: Do you want myMap to be a list of four maps (i.e., `List[Map[String,String]]`?

Comment: Yes, but not so clear. I am assumping we can have many map values, but looking at the example in terms of primary key, it may well be non sensical. I seem to remember doing an RDD example of airports that made more sense based on codes.

Comment: I think you have a point.

Comment: In your question (second code block) you say that your map works fine, but you are missing the first person, is that intended?

Comment: no it was not but it is sorted. it was a contrived example though. i thought it would gandle the list of list if string automatically, but that was my folly

Comment: handle + of - forgive the spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myList.grouped(4).toList` returns a nested list – `List[List[String]]`.

To transform the grouped sublists into `Map`s:

```
val myMap = myList.grouped(4).toList.
  map(_.map(_.split("=")).map(a => (a(0) -> a(1))).toMap)
// myMap: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = List(
//   Map(age -> 21, name -> xyz, profession -> Tester, city -> cuba),
//   Map(age -> 43, name -> abc, profession -> Programmer, city -> Sydney)
// )
```

Comment: OK. I am confused about the output now. I cannot see the 21, xyz output. That is there as well? As I had the same output in another way. I am normally used to seeing more than 1 set of data. When I look at the intermediate result they are all there. I suspect I am missing something still.

Comment: I guess misinterpreted your question.  Is my updated answer what you're looking for?

Comment: Indeed, but I need to think about it. _  Can it be rewritten with the text?

Comment: If you mean not using the `_` placeholder syntax, the 2nd code line can be rewritten as `map(group => group.map(text => text.split("=")).map(a => (a(0) -> a(1))).toMap)`